# how to get annotation values from Predicate reference?

Tags: java, performance, java-8, annotations

here is the source codes

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PredicateMeta {
    String name();
    int data();
    String operator();
}

public class AnnotationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Predicate p = getPred();
        // how to get annotation values of data, name and operator??
    }


    public static Predicate getPred() {
        @PredicateMeta(data = 0, name = "name", operator = "+")
        Predicate p = (o) ->  true;
        return p;
    }
}
```

How to get the values of annotation?

Also, will it be slow at runtime using annotations than using values from encapsulated fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant do this with lambdas.

If you try to get `p.getClass().getAnnotatedInterfaces()`, you will see that there is no annotations.

This is the only way to make this work:

first of all you must give your annotation `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface PredicateMeta {
    String name();
    int data();
    String operator();
}
```

then use anonymous class:

```
public static Predicate getPred() {
            return new @PredicateMeta(data = 0, name = "name", operator = "+")Predicate() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(Object o) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        }
```

so when you call this, you can get your annotation and its parameters:

```
p.getClass().getAnnotatedInterfaces()[0].getAnnotation(PredicateMeta.class)
```